# Create a variable with exclusive conditions in R

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements, recode

My data look like this

```
Q3A1<-c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
Q3A2<-c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
Q3A3<-c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
```

And I would like to create a new variable Q3L were it is coded as 1 when Q1A1, Q1A2 and Q1A3 are all equal to 1

I tried this

```
dataQ$Q3L <- ifelse(dataQ$Q3A1==1|dataQ$Q3A2==1|dataQ$Q3A3==1, 1, 0 )
```

but It seemslike it is recoding as 1 if at least one of the three equal 1, but I need the tree of them to be equal to 1

I tried this as well

```
library(dplyr)
dataQ %>%
  mutate(Q3L = case_when(Q3A1 == 1 & Q3A2 == 1 & Q3A3 == 1 ~ 1,))
```

not a success neither

Comment: `|` is OR, your code makes Q3L1 if A1 or A2 or A3 is one - as you say "if at least one of the three equal 1". You want AND with `&`, not OR with `|`. With `case_when`, you also need to tell it what to do if the condition is **not** met: `Q3L = case_when(Q3A1 == 1 & Q3A2 == 1 & Q3A3 == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)`.

Comment: thank you for all these explanations, I understand the code better now

Answer (score 6):

We can use `if_all` - by looping over the columns that `starts_with` 'Q3A' in column names, create a logical condition to check whether the column values are 1 (`.x == 1`), `if_all` returns `TRUE` only when all of the columns for a row are TRUE i.e. all 1, then coerce the logical (`TRUE/FALSE`) to binary with `+` or `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
dataQ <- dataQ %>% 
   mutate(Q3L = +(if_all(starts_with('Q3A'), ~ .x== 1)))
```

NOTE: Using `|` or `&` on a variable number of columns can be cumbersome, instead using either `if_all` or create the logical with `rowSums`

#### data

```
dataQ <- data.frame(Q3A1, Q3A2, Q3A3)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** thanks to input from @LMc: a more generalizable way would be:

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(Q3A1, Q3A2, Q3A3) %>% 
  mutate(Q3L = ifelse(select(., contains("Q3")) %>% 
                        rowSums() == ncol(.), 1, 0))
```

**First answer:**

We could check with `rowSums` and apply an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(Q3A1, Q3A2, Q3A3) %>% 
  mutate(Q3L = ifelse(select(., contains("Q3")) %>% 
                        rowSums() == 3, 1, 0))
```

```
    Q3A1  Q3A2  Q3A3   Q3L
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0     1     0
 2     1     1     1     1
 3     0     1     0     0
 4     1     1     1     1
 5     1     0     0     0
 6     1     1     1     1
 7     0     0     0     0
 8     1     0     0     0
 9     0     0     0     0
10     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: @LMc: That's a very good hint. thank you LMc!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
dataQ["Q3L"] = +(dataQ$Q3A1 & dataQ$Q3A2 & dataQ$Q3A3)
```

Output:

```
   Q3A1 Q3A2 Q3A3 Q3L
1     0    0    1   0
2     1    1    1   1
3     0    1    0   0
4     1    1    1   1
5     1    0    0   0
6     1    1    1   1
7     0    0    0   0
8     1    0    0   0
9     0    0    0   0
10    1    1    1   1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Q3L = as.numeric(all(as.logical(c_across(starts_with("Q3")))))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Or with `purrr::pmap_dbl`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Q3L = pmap_dbl(across(starts_with("Q3")), ~ all(.x == 1)))
```

Or `purrr::reduce`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Q3L = as.numeric(reduce(across(starts_with("Q3")), `&`)))
```

**Output**

```
    Q3A1  Q3A2  Q3A3   Q3L
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0     1     0
 2     1     1     1     1
 3     0     1     0     0
 4     1     1     1     1
 5     1     0     0     0
 6     1     1     1     1
 7     0     0     0     0
 8     1     0     0     0
 9     0     0     0     0
10     1     1     1     1
```

---

**How it works**

Both answers work similarly. They go row-by-row and convert the rows to logical vectors. `all` then tests if every element of the row-wise logical vector is `TRUE`. If it is then `1` is returned otherwise `0`.

`purrr::reduce` works a bit differently. For each row it reduces the row-wise vector using the `&` function into a single logical value.